# openpyxl - Unable to access excel file with openpyxl when it is open but works fine when it is closed

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I've been making this python script with openpyxl on a MAC. I was able to have an open excel workbook, modify something on it, save it, keep it open and run the script.

When I switched to windows 10, it seems that I can't modify it, save it, keep it open,  and run the script. I keep getting an [ERRNO 13] Permission denied error.

I tried to remove the read only mode on the folder I'm working on, I have all permissions on the computer, I clearly specified the save directory of my excel workbooks.

Any idea on what could be the issue?

Comment: Copying the file using XCOPY was what in the end worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56770093/read-from-excel-file-that-is-open-in-python

Answer (score 6):

Windows does not let you modify open Excel files in another program -- only Excel may modify open Excel files. You must close the file before modifying it with the script. (This is one nice thing about *nix systems.)

Comment: This comment helped me out

Comment: Is there any way to make a copy of an open Excel file on Windows using python, then open the copy? In File Explorer I can ctrl+c / ctrl+v to create a copy of an open .xlsx, but shutil functions seem to throw the same permission error.

Answer (score 2):

In your OneDrive settings >> Office (tab) >> Uncheck the "Use Office applications to sync Office files that I open" option.

[image: settings dialog]

This option is used when you want to collaborate your work on Office files with other users and want your changes to readily reflect. If you are not using it then uncheck it. And it will allow non-Office applications to read the file, which is Python in this case, while the file is open.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have write permission in order to create a excel temporary lock file in said directory...

Comment: I did, I have full control, modify, read & execute, read and write permissions for my user. Also, the script works perfectly fine when the workbooks are closed. Any idea on what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue with Excel files that are located in synced OneDrive folders. If I copy the file to a unsynced directory, openpyxl no longer has problems reading the .xlsx file while it is open in Excel.