# Read from excel file that is open in Python

Tags: python, file, permissions, copy

I have a script which pulls data from excel files every few hours. However, if one of these excel files is open, I still want to be able to read from it.

In python (openpyxl) i get permissions error when I attempt to do this.

Below is what i've tried. I thought I could catch the exception and create a temp version of the file that I could read from.

```
try:
    read_from = load_workbook(fileName)
except:
    tempFileName = "directory\\temp " + fileName + ".xlsx"
    open(tempFileName, 'wb').write(open(fileName, 'rb').read())
    read_from = load_workbook(tempFileName)
```

However I get the following error with even this:

```
----> 6         open(tempFileName, 'wb').write(open(fileName, 'rb').read())
  7         read_from = load_workbook(tempFileName)
  8     read_sheet = read_from.active

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'directory\\testfile.xlsx'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50027342/7919597

Comment: I can access an open Excel file with `load_workbook`, but not with `open()`. Which version of openpyxl and Excel are you using?

Comment: Which error do you get when using `read_from = load_workbook(fileName)` on an open file?

Comment: @Joe I get PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied for using load_workbook(fileName) on an open excel file. This is for a office 365 excel file stored on Onedrive.

When closed, "read_from = load_workbook(fileName)" works just fine.

Comment: Hm, then we have two different cases. I have Excel 2013 and the file is on a local hard drive. To the  `open()` and `load_workbook()` fail due to the same reason.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a temporary copy of the file via command line, then deleting the temporary file later seems to work ok.

```
try:
    read_from = load_workbook(fileName)
    delTempFileFlag = False
except:
    print("file: ",item,"is open, so cannot be accessed")
    tempFileName = "directory\\temp " + fileName + ".xlsx"
    command = "xcopy \"" + fileName + "\" " + "\"" + tempFileName + "*\""
    os.system(command)
    print("Temporary copy of file created to work with")
    read_from = load_workbook(tempFileName)
    delTempFileFlag = True
...
...
if delTempFileFlag == True:
    os.remove(tempFileName)
    delTempFileFlag = False
```

Comment: Note: This was posted by the questioner as part of the question; I've moved it to a Community Wiki answer

Comment: This works for me too, but shutil.copy does not work - I get the same error. Why is that? Is there a way to get it to work like using XCOPY without building a command as a string to send to the OS?

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote your code as

```
fh_in = open(fileName, 'rb')
fh_out = open(tempFileName, 'wb')

f_in_content = fh_in.read()
fh_out.write(f_in_content)
```

to see where the error acutally happens. In my case it was not due to the input file being open, but the output file.

Reading the file works fine, but when I tried to write the to the target file it failed with a `PermissionError`.

Comment: It sounds like you have a different problem to the one stated in the question...